# meaning of "staff" in the title "senior staff software engineer"

Tags: word-meaning

What's meaning of the word *staff* when it is used in a person's title called *senior staff software engineer*?

The dictionary definition for this word is *the group of people who work for an organization*, but it is just one person here. So apparently, it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: It means he's part of or a member of, the staff.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When *staff* appears in a title, it indicates a higher level in the hierarchy than for the same title without the word *staff*.  Here is an example (from high rank to low):

- Senior Staff Software Engineer
- Senior Software Engineer
- Software Engineer
- Junior Software Engineer

Elements of job titles do not have globally defined meanings.  What *staff* means may differ from company to company, but in many companies, *staff* will be experienced personnel who can be called in to help straighten out projects in need of guidance, acting as a knowledge or resource pool rather than as line programmers.

Comment: +1 I think this use of 'staff' is drawn from the military distinction between 'line' officers who command combat units and 'staff' officers who are attached to the central command and handle administrative, planning and logistical functions.

Comment: For example, a Staff Sergeant is one rank higher than a Sergeant in the US Army.

Comment: For programmers, should just be Software engineer 0, 1, 2, 3 ... n :-) Google also uses that nomenclature as well apparently: https://www.glassdoor.com/Salary/Google-Software-Engineer-II-Salaries-E9079_D_KO7,27.htm | https://www.glassdoor.com/Salary/Google-Software-Engineer-III-Salaries-E9079_D_KO7,28.htm (with Romans to make it fancy)

Answer (score 2):

"Senior staff" means that the person is senior within the whole company, not just with reference to the engineering department or function. As such, s/he is higher than just a "senior engineer," who is "senior" only within the engineering department.

The "senior staff" person has access to higher ups at the corporate level, above the (engineering) departmental level, and is their representative. But s/he also knows engineering.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the same meaning of the word *staff* as the common meaning where “the staff” is all the employees of a company. In “staff engineer”, *staff* is an adjective which conveys a level of seniority. From what I've seen, a “staff engineer” is more senior than a “senior engineer”, but less than a “principal engineer”. There is no “official” definition and the usage can vary between companies.

The general idea about these seniority levels is how much influence the person has: junior engineers generally do what they're told; senior engineers influence the other people on their team and neighboring teams; staff engineers have some influence on other people inside and outside of their company and have a significant impact on the design of the product; principal engineers have significant influence outside their own team and usually have been the main influence behind a new product.

The meaning is loosely related to “the officers chiefly responsible for the internal operations of an institution or business” and “the personnel who assist a director in carrying out an assigned task” (meanings 5a and 5d in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/staff)), which derives from military usage (M-W 5b), but not exactly the same. A *staff engineer* is not necessarily particularly responsible for internal operations and the role is not particularly about assisting directors.

The meaning of “staff engineer” seems to be mysterious enough that a number of people spend some energy in attempting to define it, for example:

- [*What does Staff level mean at GitLab?* by Charlie Ablett](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/02/18/staff-level-engineering-at-gitlab/)
- [*What a Senior Staff Software Engineer Actually Does* by Joy Ebertz](https://medium.com/box-tech-blog/what-a-senior-staff-software-engineer-actually-does-f3fc140d5f33)
- [StaffEng](https://staffeng.com/), [StaffEng FAQ](https://staffeng.com/faq)

Note that the usage is different in different professions. For example, a [“senior nurse”](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/senior+nurse) is short for “senior staff nurse” and is above [“staff nurse”](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/staff+nurse). The usage ultimately comes from military practice, where a [staff officer](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/staff-officer) is an officer who assists high-ranking officers directly, but the nuance conveyed by the word *staff* has evolved.

See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/563389/usage-of-staff-as-a-seniority-level-staff-engineer about how widespread this usage is.